# What are the app memory limits for Windows 10?

Tags: win-universal-app

The app memory limits for Windows Phone 8.1 are easily found on MSDN. But I cannot seem to find definitive info on memory limits for apps on Windows 10, and especially Windows 10 Mobile.

What are the limits for each device family (Xbox, desktop, phone, IoT)?

Comment: AFAIK, Microsoft doesn't impose a limit on your app's memory usage. It will however, suspend and close apps when another app requires more memory and there isn't any left (Although on desktop, I've seen it do that when my memory usage reaches 85-90%).

Comment: I am more interested in the app memory limits for the mobile device family, as that is the lowest memory devices I will be targeting.

Comment: I suggest you just test your app out on a lower end device, you can use the emulator for that if you don't have access to one. I think the minimum RAM size is 512MB (versus 128MB for W8.1). You can then add a minimum requirement to the manifest file as well. I've also stumbled upon the Windows.System namespace, which exposes a few API's you can use to ask the system how much RAM you're using: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/apps/windows.system.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found they are available as follows:

1. `Windows.System.MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsage` = current memory usage
   (unsigned long)
2. `Windows.System.MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLevel` = 0, 1, 2, etc.
3. `Windows.System.MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLimit` = for 512 MB
   models seems to be fixed to 185 MB, for 1GB models is 390 MB, and so
   on (unsigned long)

In our testings, a `OutOfMemoryException` is raised when `AppMemoryUsage` is close to `AppMemoryUsageLimit` and a new object cannot be allocated in contiguous free memspace. Seems that `AppMemoryUsageLimit` cannot be changed and is a fixed amount depending on the installed RAM, but not pretty sure for the moment.

Comment: So in other words, the limits are the same as Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: Yes. Please note that those limits seems applicable only when dealing with Universal Apps on smartphones. On regular PCs we found the limit to be 15% more than installed memory. For a 8GB-RAM the limit is about 9.2GB, for 16GB-RAM is about 18.7GB, perhaps due to the ability of paging to disk.

Comment: @CarlosAlejandroPérez I'm not finding that true at all. UWP apps on PC are still bounded to 2GB in my experience.. Unless you have some other valid settings configured to go beyond that.